# Meaning of "this or that university"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Most of the american writers have in turn gentrified themselves leaving society for **this or that university**.

What does this phrase exactly means?

Comment: "This or that university" means "one university or another".  It means the writers have taken jobs at various universities.

Answer (score 2):

> this or that
>   this and that

is a description used when being nonspecific while implying there is a choice, depending on usage it could mean *whatever* or *any*

Your sentence is saying

> The writers left society to go to a selection of universities, they did not all go to the same university.

Your phrase is often collocated with *a little of* or *some of*

> Q: Did you get anything to eat at the buffet?
>
> A: Yes, I had *a little of* **this** and *a little of* **that**.  There was a wide selection.